# AWS VPC Connection (IPSec) DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, internal-dns, amazon-vpc

Good morning,

we have etablished an ipsec tunnel to our VPC. Now we want to resolve DNS Entrys we have in our Windows Server DNS (local network) on VPC Instances. At the moment we can only work with IP Adresses.

Which is the best way to get that working? We don't want to create an A Record on local network and additionally in VPC.

Thank you

(Sorry for my bad english)

---

Local Network <-> Router IPSec <-> VPC

Answer (score 0):

In the DHCP scope options for your VPC hosts, point them to your local network resolvers.